# How do i load my sample data to Azure data lake and visualize in Power Bi?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a sample data (.CSV)  and I'm able to visualize the same in my **Power Bi desktop** by using get data->text file. I want to load the same data into **Azure data lakes** so that i can access it from  get data-> Azure data lake storage in my Power BI.

My azure data factory and my Power Bi accounts are trial ones. How do i load data into my azure data lake? When i try to do it it is asking for my git repository which is not necessary i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

To get your sample data into the Data Lake, you can go into the Azure Portal, find the data lake object and find the 'Storage Explorer' option. That will open up a file manager like interface to allow folder creation and upload files.

[image]

You can also use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/features/storage-explorer/) to load the file.

To load the data in a continuing process, you can use Azure Data Factory. You haven't mentioned if your Data Lake is Gen 1 or Gen 2, but the MS Docs website give a good start on how to use a copy activity to push files to the data lake

Gen 1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-store

Gen 2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2

Comment: I have been referring to the Gen 2 docs u have suggested. But the thing is "copy data" option is disabled and i'm not able to proceed.